# d3 move circles on y axis update

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple multi line chart that has circles on each data point.  I have coded in the ability to disable one or many lines which can update the Y axis.  For example if I remove the line that has the highest value on the Y axis the Y axis will redraw to update the scale.  When this happens the lines will also update to the new scale, but I can't get the circles to update their location with the lines.

Here are relevant bits:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.pfcLevel; }));
```

Here is the function to update the Y axis (works):

```
function rescaleY() {
    y.domain([0, getMaxY()]);
    svg.select(".y").transition()
        .duration(1000).ease("sin-in-out")
        .call(yAxis);
}
```

Here is the function to update the lines (works):

```
function updateLines() {
    svg.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(500)
        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 20; })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(d.values);
        });
}
```

And here is the function to update the circle locations (not working):

```
function updateCircles() {
     svg.selectAll(".circle")
         .transition().duration(500)
         .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
         .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d.pfcLevel) });
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks off in the code that you included. Maybe you forgot to actually assign those circles a "circle" class? Do you get a non-zero number when you run `svg.selectAll(".circle").size()`?

Comment: set up a fiddle if you can, we can have a look ?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/5ewLxpre/3/

Clicking on the rectangles in the right hand legend will enable/disable the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements with class `circle` are `g` elements, they have no `cy` attribute.  The selector should be:

```
svg.selectAll(".circle circle")
  .transition().duration(500)
  ...
```