# d3.js update nested data circles (enter.merge() ) following axis update?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My first d3 project is nearly done - it's a d3.js to be integrated into a R shiny dashboard using r2d3 (current working version here: https://awkruijt.shinyapps.io/reliability_diff_dashboard/  Version in which I try to get it to update the y axis on the left hand plot but can't manage to make it also move the circles to their new position here: https://awkruijt.shinyapps.io/relDB_plotleft_not_updating_correctly/).

In both versions posted above, the right hand plot updates the x axis when dots are dragged outside of it's current area. Now I am trying to implement the same for the left hand plot, but then updating the y-axis. However: I can't get the code that works for the right hand plot to work for the left hand plot - most specifically: I can't get it to move the dots to their new position (the lines update fine). I suspect that this has everything to do with the left hand plot using nested data.

There is a *very* similar question here: [d3 move circles on y axis update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730783/d3-move-circles-on-y-axis-update) but even with the answers provided there I can't seem to get it to run.

This is the code I use to draw the circles initially:

```
 focus.selectAll('circles')
   .data(dById)
   .enter().append("g")
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
   .enter().append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.tt); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.RT); })
   .attr("r", 6)
   .style('cursor', 'pointer')
   .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.ID); })
   .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.ID); });
```

And this is more or less the code that I am thinking ought to update the circles after the y-axis has been updated:

```
// transition the data dots  
  var circles = focus.selectAll("circles");
//  .data(dById)
//  .enter().append("g")
//  .merge(circles);

  var circle = circles.selectAll("circle");
//    .data(function(d) {return d.values;});

 focus.selectAll("circle")
   .enter().append("circle")
    .merge(circle)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.tt);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.RT);});
```

<strike>Of course I would love to present you with a working fiddle but I seem unable to get it to actually run - here's my attempt: 
https://jsfiddle.net/96Lma1cx/</strike>
Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngko820e/

Any help would be loads appreciated!

Comment: if you look at the console you see why the fiddle doesn't work

Comment: Thanks!  Quite likely fiddle has a built-in console option(?) but I ended up using the browser's console and figuring out that I need to define svg in the fiddle version of the script, and also that there was a shiny reference not commented out yet. I also gave the svg a fill colour to make clear where it's boundaries are. 

Updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/62s43o1j/

Comment: scratch that URL, it's actually here: https://jsfiddle.net/ngko820e/

Comment: look in the console and fix all the errors first

Comment: look what happens if you drag the circles into the negative numbers

Comment: That seems perfectly sage advice, yet... the errors don't make sense to me?  

It indicates that d is NULL in the connectLine() bit at the end of dragged(d) - yet it executes that part of code perfectly fine, as does anywhere else where "d" is called upon, just not the circles bit in dragended(d). There seems to be something about selecting the correct bit of data from nested data that keeps escaping me.

Comment: Sorry - it took me over 20 minutes to write the above comment so I missed the negative numbers clue.. trying to work that one out now.

Comment: log the result of your selection and find out why d is NULL

Comment: so, the modifiers I used to create some extra space at either end of the scale weren't too well thought through (there actually ought to be a limit on the values so that they can't extend into the negative domain but that's a different issue I am gonna let pass I think), so for now I modified the y.domain calls to:

         y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
             return d.RT;
           }),
           d3.max(data, function(d) {
             return d.RT;
           })

Still no joy...

Comment: I am sorry.. I do not know how to  (this being my first time doing anything in JS). 
Using "console.log(d)", it is now clear to me that 'd' represents only the one line that was dragged at the start of dragended. However, I was under the impression that the focus.selectAll calls were to remedy this. I do not know (and seem unable to google) how to send the current selection to the console, so I can't check what d represents beyond the first point were it throws an error (the connectLine() bit, which despite the error seemingly does execute correctly).

Comment: Could you (or anyone else?) of any further help?

Am grateful that, thanks to your help so far, I now understand better how to use the console yet after a further 5 hours of fiddling I am precisely as far as I was after 1,5 days when I first posted: I understand that I am not selecting the correct data/the data at the correct level.

I can also see why adjustments that I try don't work, although I do not understand why the return connectLine(d.values) works even though it throws an error due to the "paths" not having an attribute "d".

I am just really stuck here for days now  :/

Comment: Woah woah!! progress!!!   so.. I figured out to get rid of the d = null errors by calling upon path.line instead of just line and upon circle.dots instead of circles (after adding an .attr("class", "dots") to the initial circles) - and now it essentially works!! \o/   

Only thing left is that the old yaxis doesn't disapper (which I sort of had hoped would sort itself automatically once all the lines and circles were updated properly). hoping to report back soon that that's sorted too!  Woohoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final working version: https://jsfiddle.net/2qmygfvx/

The problem was indeed in selecting the correct data at each stage which I eventually ended up solving by calling upon (and adding as needed) classes for the different elements.

Here a tidbit of specific code to update the circles:

```
     // transition the data dots 
     var circledots = focus.selectAll("circle.dots")

     focus.selectAll("circle.dots")
       .enter().append("circle")
       .merge(circledots)
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
         return x(d.tt);
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
         return y(d.RT);
       });
```

How on earth people would see the console was a mystery for me up till now and am grateful to rioV8 for pushing me towards using the browser's console.